# State is not populated to my View

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, filter

I have followed the article on the Joomla Developer Sites to create a sorting filter for my list (https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_sortable_columns_to_a_table_in_a_component).

But I cannot get it work. Step 2 explains how to get the State of the sorting. But the state is **NULL** after calling get GetState-Method. Here is the Method I have used.
`$state = $this->get('State');`


Best regards
tria1312

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of `$state = $this->get('State');` is `$state = $model->getState();` where $model is the current model of your view.

If your model is extending from `JModelList`, all your state variables are automatically populated (provided correct values present in request). Otherwise populate the state in your model's populateState function.

```
protected function populateState ($ordering = 'sort_order', $direction = 'ASC')
{
  $orderCol = $app->input->get('filter_order', $ordering);
  $this->setState('list.ordering', $orderCol);
}
```

Note: Never call getState function in populateState, which creates infinite loop.

Comment: Does it also work with the JModelLegacy Class?

Comment: Yes. you can add your own populateState method in your model and populate the values from request manually.

Comment: OK, thats working. And now I want to have the state populated when a request with special task is called. How does this work? In that case my list.ordering is always empty.

Comment: I found it. You have to fetch the State by calling the Method $app->getUserState( 'list.column', 'default_column_name' );